# Copiar TAG específica de arquivo XML e mesclar com outro arquivo XML

Tags: java, c#

Situação:
- Preciso de um único arquivo XML que contenha os dados de todos os outros arquivos existentes e os que estão por vir. Mas não posso simplesmente juntar um arquivo com o outro sendo que preciso de apenas uma tag específica.

Existe algum jeito de fazer isso em C# ou em Java?

Help

Comment: Sim, é possível tanto em Java quanto em C#. Só não é possível conter os dados dos arquivos que ainda estão por vir... Apresente o código de como você está tentando realizar essa mesclagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer de forma simples usando XPathNavigator no C#. Neste caso estou colocando a nf junto com um arquivo notasGeral.xml onde fica todas as notas fiscais.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load("nf1.xml");
            XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
            navigator.MoveToChild("nfeProc", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");

            XPathDocument newBooks = new XPathDocument("C:\\Program Files\\VertrigoServ\\www\\Prototipo\\notasGeral.xml");
            XPathNavigator newBooksNavigator = newBooks.CreateNavigator();
            newBooksNavigator.MoveToChild("nfeProc", "");

            foreach (XPathNavigator nav in newBooksNavigator.SelectDescendants("NFe", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", false))
            {
                navigator.AppendChild(nav);
            }

            document.Save("C:\\Program Files\\VertrigoServ\\www\\Prototipo\\notasGeral.xml");
            label1.Text = ("Concluído!");
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
```